# Why is this code deadlocking?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I need some help concerning deadlocks. I just do not understand why my code is deadlocking here.

I tried different scenarios.

However I still can't find why and where is the problem. Normally it should work
and I don't find where the deadlock is between `debuter` and `termine`.

```
  public class Interblocking {
           protected object obj = object();
           private boolean condition = true;

           public synchronized void debuter() {
               synchronized(obj) {
                   while (!condition) {
                       try {
                           obj.wait();
                       } catch (InterruptedExeption ie) {}
                   }
                   condition = false;
               }
           }

           public synchronized void terminer() {
               synchronized(obj) {
                   condition = true;
                   obj.notifyAll();
               }
           }
        }
```

Comment: Well, given that you haven't said what the purpose of this class is, it's very difficult to answer this question...

Comment: why the specified class  below describes a classic case of deadlock? Give a scenario illustrating such default.

Comment: that is the question ;) wich i have difficulties of understanding

Comment: Is it homework? If so, please tag it as homework. Also, there can be a deadlock if there are some threads doing things. What do your threads do with this class?

Comment: yes it a homework and the given statement is what i explained before i have no clue what the threads are doing i just know there has to be thread1 T1, thread2 T2, thread3 T3 ... and so on

Comment: "i have no clue what the threads are doing" - it's going to be very hard to figure out why they're deadlocking.

Comment: This doesn't come close to compiling.

Comment: @Dardan on an unrelated note, according to code standards, Java class names should not start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @Matt Davis: while thread which runs debuter() makes wait(), it releases the lock, and terminer() can freely proceed. No deadlock occurs.

Comment: Note on code style: better synchronize on this rather than on obj. If syncing on this is not appropriate, create a separate class and move there condition and both methods.

Comment: I only just noticed that the methods synchronize on both this and obj. So my 2 comments are wrong. Make syncing on this only to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit (new answer)

Method `wait()` doesn't release all locks of current Thread.

So when A thread invokes `debuter` it releases only `obj` lock but holds `this` lock so other threads can't invoke `terminer` method.

Here is example:

```
class WaitReleaseTest implements Runnable {
    Object lockA, lockB;
    public WaitReleaseTest(Object lockA, Object lockB) {
        this.lockA = lockA;
        this.lockB = lockB;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + " attempting to acquire lockA");
        synchronized (lockA) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + " attempting to acquire lockB");
            synchronized (lockB) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + " holds lockA = " + Thread.holdsLock(lockA));
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + " holds lockB = " + Thread.holdsLock(lockB));
                try {
                    lockB.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Object o1=new Object();
        Object o2=new Object();
        new Thread(new WaitReleaseTest(o1,o2)).start();
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
        new Thread(new WaitReleaseTest(o1,o2)).start();
    }
}
```

output

```
Thread-0 attempting to acquire lockA
Thread-0 attempting to acquire lockB
Thread-0 holds lockA = true
Thread-0 holds lockB = true
Thread-1 attempting to acquire lockA
... now it waits
```

Comment: thank you very much as i understand this is the solution to bypass deadlocking

Comment: @Dardan JB Nizet has right so my answer won't solve your problem.

Comment: is this right then? You have two locks here:

   Instance of the class interblocing (because you're using
synchronized methods.)
   Instance of obj (because you're using synchronized(obj) and then
waiting and notifying on it.

Now, if thread A goes to debuter() method and waits on obj, thread B
can't go to terminer() to do obj.notifyAll() because thread A is still
holding the monitor lock of the interblocing class instance. Therefore
it deadlocks.

Comment: @Dardan You just answerd your question. I thought that wait() releases all threads locks but it doesn't. So when A thread invokes `debuter` then it releases only `obj` lock but holds `this` lock so other threads cant invoke `terminer`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code is total different from what your code is able to do.

You probably want a thread entering **debuter** to wait until **condition** is to true;

The basic problem are the **synchronized** keyword on the method. They assure that only thread is in any method of your instance of **Interblocking**

Remove **synchronized** on the methods.

The next problem is **condition**. It is undefined how may thread becomes released after called terminer

You run into a dead lock on the second call to **debuter** because **condition** is false after the first call to **debuter**.
And there is no way to **execute terminer** because there is a thread in **debuter** blocking

Using multiple levels of blocking objects (in this case object and this) is always suspicious to cause a dead lock.

Comment: I dont have to make this code work I only have to answer why this code performs Deadlocks thank u

Answer (score 0):

The code does not contain deadlock conditions. Deadlocks occur when there are cycles in the graph of resources. You have only one resource (obj) so the resource graph consists of single node and cannot contain cycles.

While `debuter` may wait  for`condition`, `terminer` never waits for long time.

Comment: That is wrong. terminer will not be executed when a thread is in debuter.

Comment: Yes I was wrong. I only just noticed that the methods synchronize both on this and obj. Synchronization should be made only on one object, either this or obj.